# Accessing the column of a row using Index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to access a particular column value from a row using Index.

```py
>>> cli_data = df[df['Trigger_Type'] == 'CLI-Related']
>>> len(cli_data)
715

>>> cli_data.columns
Index(['Identifier', 'Status', 'Priority', 'Severity', 'Found', 'DE-manager','Age', 'Component', 'Headline', 'Trigger_Type'],dtype='object')

>>> cli_data['Headline'].head(1)
HMR1:This is a sample bug description headline
Name: Headline, dtype: object
    
>>> cli_data.shape
(715, 10)
    
>>> cli_data['Headline'][0] 
Trying to access the Headline value by Index.
```

Comment: [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) ?

Comment: Thanks Henry. iloc works. Could you kindly explain me what was the problem that I was making. I had a dataframe of say 100 values (index starting with 0) and took a sub-sett of dataframe (cli-data) which was picking the data lets assume index starting with 51 ..For the cli-data, how to reset the index to 0? because cli_data['Headline'][0] does not work where as cli_data['Headline][51] acttually works.

Comment: To reset the index, use `reset_index`.

Comment: iloc vs indexing is the question of row_number vs index. The index does not have to be 0,1,2,... After selecting a subset of the original dataframe, say, you selected rows whose indexes are 2,7,15. Then, in a new sub-dataframe, there will be three rows with row numbers 0,1,2 and indexes 2,7,15, respectively. `iloc` uses row numbers, and [] uses indexes.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Much ..